# How to personalize <title> tag with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, title

I'd like to personalize the `<title>` tag, I want it to look different from browsers' defaults. I want it to have a black background and white small text. How can I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The contents of the title tag are put in the browser title bar. This is outside the document, at the top of the browser window. You can not change the appearance  of the title bar.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible. The *title* tag is displayed on the window's title, not in the document, so you can't change the way it's displayed.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible, it's not a classic document element.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the title is displayed only as part of the browser chrome (in different ways depending on the browser) and **is not subject to styling** (at least not from a webpage, I suspect that you could style it if you were, for example, writing a XUL application instead of a webpage).

You can style it if you want it to appear in the browser viewport:

```
head, title { display: block; }
title { background: black; color: white; font-size: small; }
```

(This will only influence the title as shown in the viewport, any rendering in the browser will be unaffected)

Comment: Surely setting the `head` and `title` to display in the viewport should not be recommended? The `head` has a specific use, for specifying resources (CSS, JS etc.) used by the web page, as does the body, for the visible content of the web page. You shouldn't display the `head` and `title` tag. It likely won't work across all browsers in any case.